# Facebook flash games high scores API

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, open-source

As I am new to facebook games is there any third party API for flash games. 
Actually I used mochi highscore API but I don't want to login through mochi. Direct submission through facebook id. Let me know any third party API or suggest any tutorials.

regards,
chandu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy to post a score to the highscores in Facebook, check out the following code. All you need is a userID which you get from facebook when you log the user in and the value that you use in your game as a score like experience, points or whatever.

```
// post experience as score
$experience = 1000; // get this from your database 
$contents = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."&client_secret=".FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY."&grant_type=client_credentials");

$exploded = explode("=",$contents);

$accessToken = $exploded[1];
$score_URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userFacebookID . '/scores';
$score_result = https_post($score_URL,
  'score=' . $experience
  . '&access_token=' . $accessToken
);
```

https_post function looks like this :

```
function https_post($uri, $postdata) 
{
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

You can put this in your index.php after you get the facebook user ID and their score will be sent every time they come to the game.

Hope that helps.